# Calling PHP class in Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a PHP-class handling authorization and requests to an API and I would like to use those functions in Angular. When the PHP is loaded I create a controller which initializes a variable which should contain the response from the API. I think it should look something like this:

```
$scope.jsonData = <?php echo json_encode(PHPClass::getData("Argument")); ?>;
```

Is there any way to do this and use the PHP-class and refrain from using $http?

Comment: Much cleaner to pass to a javascript variable in it's own script tag so you can separate js into js files and not mix in php code. Then reference that variable in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I've been going about this the wrong way. I'll instead start looking into it properly authorizing the requests through angularjs.